# DraftProjectResource->IsGenericResource returning wrong value

Tags: csom, project-server

I am using CSOM to traverse through Project Server 2013 resources on a project. I am checking if the resources are generic since I have written code logic based on that. I have a BA and PM generic resources that are part of a project that I added using the Build Team feature in Project Server. These resources show up with the Generic flag checked ON when viewing them in resource center. But programmatically the `IsGenericResource` flag is returning `False`.

Here is the code snippet (relevant code within **) :

```
public string ProcessGenericResources(ProjectContext pc, PublishedProject publishedproject)
{
    try
    {
            Boolean bStaffingRequestItemUpdated = false; // this will be set to True whenever a staffing list item is update
            string sResourceApproverAttr = ExceptionUtility.ReadKeyFromConfig(sResourceApproverKey);
            string sRet = "";
            DraftProject project;

            if (publishedproject.IsCheckedOut)
               project = publishedproject.Draft.IncludeCustomFields;
            else
               project = publishedproject.CheckOut().IncludeCustomFields;

             pc.Load(project, p => p.Name, p => p.Id);
             DraftProjectResourceCollection ProjectResources = project.ProjectResources;
             pc.Load(ProjectResources, list => list.Include(item => item.Name, item => item.Id, item => item.IsGenericResource));
             pc.ExecuteQuery();
              // For each generic resource, check if an item is already in the Staffing Request list. If not create one
              foreach (DraftProjectResource resource in ProjectResources)
              {
                 List<string> listRMsNotified = new List<string>(); // this is to keep track of RMs already notified
                 pc.Load(resource);
                 pc.ExecuteQuery();
                 **bool bGenericResource = resource.IsGenericResource;
         ExceptionUtility.LogMessage("Resource=> Name:" + resource.Name + " ID:" + resource.Id + " Is Generic Resource?: " + bGenericResource);**
```

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow.  I tweaked your post to fix the formatting of the code you submitted, and added the CSOM tag, in case some experts interested in that might be able to help.

Comment: GreenAsJade,Thanks for fixing the formatting and adding the CSOM ta. I found my answer

Answer (score 1):

I found the issue. Apparently ProjectResource is not the same as EnterpriseResource. For each ProjectResource in a Project you will need to find a match in the ProjectContext.EnterpriseResources collection. The record in EnterpriseResources collection shows the correct value in the IsGeneric attribute.